# Run Gradle task before IntellijIDEA artifact creation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, build, intellij-14

I want to execute some task before every build of project.

I'm using something like this:

```
compileJava.dependsOn('myTask')
```

and everything works perfect for commands like:

```
gradle build
gradle test
gradle war
// etc.
```

But this solution doesn't work with IntelliJ IDEA creation of Artifacts for deploy.
My task doesn't get executed.

Comment: If you have a custom task for artifacts creation, you can make your task depends on your build task. For example:
task createArtifact( dependsOn: myTask )
Is that the case?